# How to edit all Apache's error codes DIRECTLY instead of using httpd.conf?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, configuration

When a page does not exist.. this is what 
I see on the web :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /test was not found on this server.
```

I know about :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /test.html
```

but I rather not use that. I rather find where this above is originating from.. and modify that directly.

perhaps it would be faster + more efficient this way. given that it would be a more "direct" dealing. (transaction )

Answer (score 0):

It'd appear you're looking for `modules/http/http_protocol.c` in the Apache source code. See, for example, `get_canned_error_string()`. (NOTE: This is from a quick glance, I did not investigate the source in depth or build/test Apache with modified error messages.)

But really, there is nothing particularly inefficient or slow about using `ErrorDocument`, especially since errors should not be on the "hot path". (That is, the *vast* majority of requests to your server should not result in errors).